# Terraform - Joining infrastructure and application configurations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, terraform

I have 2 scripts for Terraform:

1. Used to launch the infrastructure (VPC, Security groups, MySQL, Redis, Cassandra) servers.
2. Used to launch the application (Auto scale groups, Load balancers, DNS Records).

My question is what is the best practice on managing those configuration files.
I wish for both applications to be in the same AWS VPC (which will be created from the infrastructure `.tf` file)

**EDIT**:
To further clear my point, I have this setup in regards to Terraform:

- git repo infra

  - infra.tf
  - vpc.tf
- git repo application

  - app.tf
  - load_balancers.tf

I want to have all `*.tf` configuration to be deployed into the same AWS VPC, in 2 phases: first the infra .tf files and then the app .tf.

Comment: Put them in a git repo?

Comment: @FlorinAsăvoaie i'm keeping them in a git repository, that wasn't my point, my point is how to take 2 independant terraform setups and have them deployed into a single AWS VPC (which is created from one of the terraform setups)

Answer (score 0):

This sort of layered configuration is possible with Terraform, but it requires an intermediate store to retain the information from the first config (infrastructure, in your case) so it can be retrieved when applying the second config (application).

The most straightforward way to do this is to use Terraform's built in "remote state" mechanism as the intermediate store. To do this, you'd first configure a remote backend (assuming Terraform 0.9 or later) in the infrastructure configuration. For example, using Amazon S3 for storage:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "example-state-bucket"
    key    = "infrastructure.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

Each time the backend configuration changes it's necessary to run `terraform init` to synchronize the state to the new location.

Any information you wish to expose to the application config must be declared as an "output" of the infrastructure config:

```
output "aws_vpc_id" {
  value = "${aws_vpc.example.id}"
}

output "aws_subnet_a_id" {
  value = "${aws_subnet.a.id}"
}

output "aws_subnet_b_id" {
  value = "${aws_subnet.b.id}"
}
```

After adding a new output, run `terraform apply` to ensure that its value is computed and written into the state.

Finally we are ready to read this value from the application configuration using the `terraform_remote_state` data source:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "infrastructure" {
  backend = "s3"

  config {
    # Config values should match that of the infrastructure backend settings
    # as shown above.
    bucket = "example-state-bucket"
    key    = "infrastructure.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}

# For example, to create an EC2 instance in one of the subnets
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  # ...
  subnet_id = "${data.terraform_remote_state.infrastructure.aws_subnet_a_id}"
}
```

A more elaborate example of this pattern, using Consul as the intermediate data store rather than Terraform remote state, can be seen in my series of articles about [the Terraform Environment+Application Pattern](http://apparently.me.uk/terraform-environment-application-pattern/). Any data store that Terraform can both write to and read from can, in principle, be used to pass data from one configuration to another.